Exclude certain references from bibliography list using apacite
I am using overleaf and I want to exclude specific references which are present in my bibliography.bib from my bibliography list. I have cited my references of interviews in this way, but I do not want them to appear in my bibliography. For example:
@misc{Interview1,
    author={Participant1},
    year={2024},
    howpublished={personal communication},
}


\usepackage{apacite}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

I am using the \usepackage{apacite} package for apa citing. I have tried biblatex to exclude these interviews, which works, but this is not showing all my references and parentheses are missing in my citations. Does anyone know how to exclude certain references from my bibliography while using the apacite package?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please -- as usual here -- show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

I'm a bit confused by your question. If you don't cite the items, they won't show up in the bibliography. So you exclude things just by not citing them. Or do you want citation callouts for them without actual bibliography entries?

Yes! I do cite them in my thesis, but I do not want them to appear in the bibliography list.

Ok, this is very hard to do with apacite I think, but with biblatex you can assign a category to them and exclude them that way. If biblatex is an acceptable solution for you, then you should edit your question to show what you've tried with it and we'll try to fix the problem that you describe when you tried it.
